# Why "boolean" becomes "false & true" in PayloadAction in redux-starter-kit?

Tags: typescript, redux

I am using redux-starter-kit in React project. I am trying to describe type of action payload in reducer in createSlice method.

I have two reducers:

```js
setFetchingMenuItems: (
  state: IPagesState,
  { payload }: PayloadAction<boolean>
) => {
  state.isFetchingMenuItems = payload;
},
setMenuItems: (
  state: IPagesState,
  { payload }: PayloadAction<IMenuItemViewModel[]>
) => {
  state.menuItems = payload;
},
```

The second one works as expected. If I try to dispatch setMenuItems action, it accepts only array of IMenuItemViewModel.

But if I try to dispatch setFetchingMenuItems action with true or false payload, TypeScript shows me error: "TS2345: Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'false & true'."

What I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my async method where I dispatch actions:

```js
export const fetchMenuItems = () => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch
): Promise<void> => {
  dispatch(setFetchingMenuItems(true));

  try {
    const { value } = await PageService.getMenuItems();

    dispatch(setMenuItems(value));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  dispatch(setFetchingMenuItems(false));
};
```

TypeScript version is 3.5.1.

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet, where you call your `setFetchingMenuItems` method? Also is updating Typescript version an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in redux-starter-kit (I had version 0.5.1). Version [0.6.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit/releases/tag/v0.6.0) fixes it. So I updated to 0.6.2 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion to `true | false` seems to be an [active issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30029) with Typescript. What seems strange is that it's expanded to `false & true` instead of `false | true`.

To fix your problem you could try replacing `boolean` with `false | true`.

Comment: Now I have this: `PayloadAction<false | true>`. But nothing changed. Error is the same.